# How to remove original WhatsApp UIActivity in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, whatsapp

I want to remove WhatsApp Activity icon in UiActivityViewController beacause I create a custom Activity WhatsApp.

In avc.excludedActivityTypes I don't have WhatsApp :-/

Can you help me ?

Thank You !

Comment: no , we can't hide this

Comment: Do you want to remove the icon only? I'm afraid we can't remove only icon of an UIActivity. You can replace it with another icon or remove the entire activity from UIActivityViewController. In my case, I changed the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UiActivityViewController. Rather use the ones from the SDKs you want to them (Facebook, Twitter..)