# iOS sharing image and URL to whatsapp using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

Sharing image and URL using UIActivityViewController works fine for facebook and  gmail but didn't work for whatsapp. Here's the code i used

```
- (void)share {
    UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screen.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [keyWindow drawViewHierarchyInRect:keyWindow.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *snapShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImage *imageToShare = snapShotImage;

    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

    NSMutableArray *activityItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:urlToShare, imageToShare, nil];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[
                                                     UIActivityTypePrint,
                                                     UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                     UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAirDrop];


    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

1. Have I miss anything?
2. Do i need to implement custom activity for whatsapp?

Note: Incase of 2 we need to find this [hiding whatsapp from activityviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906835/how-to-remove-original-whatsapp-uiactivity-in-uiactivityviewcontroller) solution before proceeding

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: I have not excluded UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard. Atleast user can copy and paste it what's app if direct is not working.

Comment: sorry, doesn't work for facebook app too.

Comment: Not working, Can you pls help me to Post the image to Facebook?

Answer (score 10):

WhatsApp has updated policies which doesn't allow simple text to be shared along with Image or URL or Document.

If you are trying to share image and URL separately, it will take the last object from the array and will share that.

You can send the image this way:

```
NSMutableArray *activityItems= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:img, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypeAirDrop];    
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Also you would need to set permission in Plist file for iOS9**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>
```

Comment: Any option to share both image and text , currently can't share image and text both .

Comment: @JaywantKhedkar Nope it is not still NOT possible to share image and text.
However you can share an URL along with some text.
May be you can share the image URL if you are getting the image from server along with some custom text that you want to share.

Comment: Thank you , I will try with your solution hope so it will work for me .

Answer (score 5):

You can't share image and text both in WhatsApp using UIActivityViewController. Only single thing you can post. That is image or text.

Comment: Any option to share both image and text , I want to share both image and text